# Rephrasing "a field is becoming ripe for" or "maturing" with a more appropriate sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a scientific article in collaboration with a colleague. We wrote

> "studies of this field are becoming ripe for further exploration...".

Something about the word "ripe" in this sentence is not nice but I can not seem to get successful at rephrasing it in a better way. Some of the sentences I tried:

> Research in this field is maturing.
>
> Findings in this field are becoming amenable to deeper investigations.

They are still awful. Any suggestions/hints to write this better by the masters of the art in this great forum will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**[blossom](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blossom)**?

> 1.1 Mature or develop in a promising or healthy way.
>
> [Oxford]

Some relevant example sentences from the entry:

- ‘‘I believe there are sufficient areas particularly in the energy sector that one can see burgeoning and blossoming in trade development,’ he said.’
- ‘What started as a few health-care providers twenty years ago has blossomed into a robust community that boasts international connections.’

Comment: I'll admit I don't think this is the best fit. I'll keep thinking.

Comment: "growing more robust for further exploration" might be one step closer. Yeah, bloom and ripe are of flowers and fruits hence they come across as meaningless. I hope you get a fantastic inspiration for fixing this. Cheers

Comment: "growing more robust for further exploration"  is so verbose and clunky, though. Who is your article intended for? Is it for technical experts in the field?

Comment: Yes, it's a sentence part of a scientific article I'm writing to publish in a journal.

Comment: I agree it is clunky. I think I'm having a writer block when it comes to this sentence. Your comments and answers have given me nice hints

Answer (score 0):

I've got some suggestions. This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but feel free to maybe get inspired by some of them.

---

*Findings in this field are advancing.*

**to advance** ~Merriam-Webster

> an instance of notable progress in the development of knowledge, technology, or skill:
>
> *Under her new teacher, the aspiring violinist has made noticeable advances in her technique in just a few weeks.*

---

*This field is undergoing an on-going progress/ Noticeable progress has been made in this field.*

**progress** ~Merriam-Webster

> gradual betterment; especially : the progressive development of humankind

---

*Much research has been developed in this field.* / *There have been increasing research efforts in this field.*

**to develop** or **to increase efforts**

> a : to work out the possibilities of :
>   *develop an idea*
>
> b : to create or produce especially by deliberate effort over time: 
>   *develop new ways of doing business/ develop software*

Answer (score 0):

> "studies of this nascent field are **opportune** for further
>   exploration".  "Findings in this field are **opportune** to deeper
>   investigations."

[merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/opportune)